# Passing data from iron router into template helper

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to pass in the categoryId from the iron router data into the template helper in meteor.

This is my router code:

```
Router.route('/lessons/:categoryId', function() {
this.subscribe('lessons');
this.render('Lessons', {
    data: {
        categoryId: this.params.categoryId
    }
});
```

This is my template code:

```
Template.Lessons.helpers({
lessons: function () {
console.log('CategoryId: '+categoryId);
}
});
```

How can I correctly access the categoryId that was created in iron router?

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` from your router provides the context (`this`) for your template. To access `categoryId` from your helper, use `this.categoryId`:

```js
Template.Lessons.helpers({
  lessons: function() {
    console.log('CategoryId: ' + this.categoryId);
  }
});
```

You can also access router data via:

```
Template.instance().data.categoryId;
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked.  I was having another little problem in my code that prevented me from realizing the this.categoryId had worked the first time I tried it.  I will post here in case someone else has this trouble.  It was reading my categoryId as a string instead of a number when I tried to use it.  To fix:         var categoryId = parseInt(this.categoryId);
        var lessonsData = Lessons.find({categoryId: categoryId}).fetch();